# QGIS distance matrix projection and alternative output format

Tags: qgis, distance, distance-matrix

I have around 200 thousand cities around the globe and are in a point shapefile with equidistant conic projection. I use ArcGIS and QGIS but have two problems:

1. When I use distance matrix tool, it gives me the distance in decimal degree.
2. the output file reach 12.2 GB and stop saving more records. I dont see any other format I can choose with a larger limitation.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user please take the [Tour] where you will see that there should be only one question asked per question.

Comment: Do you really have "200 thousand cities"?